# Using Tables of Records in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've declared the following types in my PL/SQL package:

```
TYPE t_simple_object IS RECORD (
   wert   NUMBER,
   gs     NUMBER,
   vl     NUMBER);

TYPE t_obj_table IS TABLE OF t_simple_object
  INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
```

Then I declare a variable:

```
obj t_obj_table;
```

However, when I want to use the variable, I cannot initialize or extend it:

```
obj := t_obj_table ();
```

gives the following errror:

```
PLS-00222: no function with name 'T_OBJ_TABLE' exists in this scope
```

If I don't initialize it, I can't extend it to add some date as

```
obj.EXTEND();
```

gives another error:

```
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'EXTEND'
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You don't extend a table indexed by "something", you can just use it...

```
DECLARE
   TYPE t_simple_object IS RECORD 
      ( wert   NUMBER
      , gs     NUMBER
      , vl     NUMBER
      ); 

   TYPE t_obj_table IS TABLE OF t_simple_object
   INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER; 

   my_rec t_simple_object;
   obj t_obj_table; 
BEGIN
   my_rec.wert := 1;
   my_rec.gs := 1;
   my_rec.vl := 1;
   obj(1) := my_rec;
END;
/
```

To use the EXTEND syntax, this example should do it...

```
DECLARE
   TYPE t_simple_object IS RECORD 
      ( wert   NUMBER
      , gs     NUMBER
      , vl     NUMBER
      ); 

   TYPE t_obj_table IS TABLE OF t_simple_object; 

   my_rec t_simple_object;
   obj t_obj_table := t_obj_table(); 
BEGIN
   obj.EXTEND;
   my_rec.wert := 1;
   my_rec.gs := 1;
   my_rec.vl := 1;
   obj(1) := my_rec;
END;
/
```

Also see [this link (Ask Tom)](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:14334298866128)

Answer (score 8):

You can not extend an assosiative array.
Just assign values to it

```
declare
  TYPE t_simple_object IS RECORD (
    wert   NUMBER,
    gs     NUMBER,
    vl     NUMBER);

  TYPE t_obj_table IS TABLE OF t_simple_object INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

  simple_object t_simple_object;
begin
  simple_object.wert := 1;
  simple_object.gs := 2;
  simple_object.vl := 3;
  obj(1) := simple_object;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to use an associative array (aka index-by table) then leave out the "INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER" clause. Your code then works OK:

```
declare 
    TYPE t_simple_object IS RECORD (
       wert   NUMBER,
       gs     NUMBER,
       vl     NUMBER);
    TYPE t_obj_table IS TABLE OF t_simple_object;
    obj t_obj_table;
begin  
    obj := t_obj_table ();
    obj.EXTEND();
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

Or just use a record ( or associate array of records )

```
create or replace package p_test is

  type t_rec is record (
    empname varchar2(50),
    empaddr varchar2(50));

  function p_test_ret_record return t_rec;

end p_test;


create or replace package body p_test is

  function p_test_ret_record return t_rec is
     l_rec t_rec;
  begin
     l_rec.empname := 'P1';
     l_rec.empaddr := 'P2';     
     return l_rec;
  end;

end p_test;

declare
  -- Non-scalar parameters require additional processing 
  result p_test.t_rec;
begin
  -- Call the function
  result := p_test.p_test_ret_record;
  dbms_output.put_line('Name: ' || result.empname || ' Addr: ' || result.empaddr);
end;
```